# Working with excel in python- method returns none

Tags: python, excel, oop, win32com

I want to create a class to ease my work when creating Excel sheets and extracting data from it. When I run the code without method it works fine and prints the value that i need.

```
import win32com.client

t= win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
t.Visible = True
t.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\shtu5t\Desktop\Feb-Mar WT     Campaign.xlsx")
t.Sheets('Working Area').Select()

print(t.ActiveSheet.Cells(87,9).Value)
```

But when I want to create a class it works fine until I want extract some data from it. It opens the file that I need and selects the sheet but doesn't get the data from a cell and returns none.

```
import win32com.client

class Excel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Eserver=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        self.Eserver.Visible=True
    def open(self,path):
        self.open=self.Eserver.Workbooks.Open(path)
    def select_sheet(self,name):
        self.select_sheet=self.Eserver.Sheets   (name).Select()
    def select_data(self,row,column):
        self.select_data=self.Eserver.ActiveSheet.Cells(row,column).Value

B=Excel()
B.open("C:\\Users\shtu5t\Desktop\Feb-Mar WT Campaign.xlsx")
B.select_sheet('Working Area')
print(B.select_data(87,1))
```

Please, could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: You don't have a `return` for `select_data` so it implicitly returns `None`. I'm not sure why you are creating a class with multiple methods for this, especially with attributes and methods sharing a name. The library already supplies those methods, there is no need to reconstruct that class in your own code.

Comment: add return statement in each method.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked. Regarding classes, i am beginner and probably i did not fully comprehend the purpose of classes and here i just wanted to avoid long scripts.